# Using Vista For Development

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-vista

My company is pushing that everyone switch to Vista on new laptops. I am using Visual Studio 2005 and SQL Server 2005 right now and had to fix some compatibility issues. I could push for XP and go through HR, but I also could just get accustomed to Vista just for experience sakes.

Any experiences with development and Vista? Pros/Cons?

Answer (score 7):

No programming issues with vista per-se. Vista SP1 has been rock solid for me.

However, I run Vista Ultimate 64-bit, so I have to target 32-bit, if I am using 32-bit compiled libraries.

Now that Vista has a few winters under its belt, it's gotten a lot better. <strike>Just make sure you disable UAC ;)</strike>

Comment: No!  Do not disable UAC.  If you do that, then you fall into the habit of never checking if your programs which you write will run with UAC.  I know it's a pain, but your customers will appreciate it.

Comment: -1 for Disable UAC. That like buying an expensive car and leaving it at the street corner with the keys in it and a sign that says "Steal me, My owner doesn't deserve this nice of a car"

Comment: I was going to +1 this... until I saw the UAC comment.  While I'm not giving it -1, I've personally not had problems with UAC getting in my face.  Now, there are OTHER things that have... like Comodo Internet Security.

Comment: Don't disable UAC - but instead do as on XP and make your user a NON-admin and go on as you've always done. Because you haven't run Windows as an admin I hope? ;p  ...Upgrade, if they pay, upgrade - it's the responsible way - think of it as a security patch. You do apply those, right? ;) *sarcastic*

Comment: Here's the thing with UAC: it will annoy you to death during the first month or so. Then 2 things happen: (1)You don't run into it as often anymore, because by now you're not messing around setting up your programs as much (2)You start to get used to the prompts that are left.  Give it a chance

Comment: IMO properly UAC is not half as bad as it's reputation. My personal firewall is nagging me much more often and I wouldn't think about disabling that either.

Comment: You are right. I shouldn't give blanket advice to disable UAC.

For me, however, I hate it, and I don't need it to bother me. Win7 lets you tone it down, but I much prefer OSX's approach.

Comment: @Russ: based on your analogy, if I run UAC, then my computer is 100% secure, and I never have to worry about it being compromised or stolen, correct?

Comment: @Alan: Wrong.  If you don't leave your keys in your car, it's still possible for someone to steal it -- it's just much harder.

Comment: @Jesse: No sure what country you live in, but in the US, thieves will steal your car, regardless of keys being left in there.

Answer (score 3):

From my own experiences, developing on Vista works just fine. Also if you're doing website development, now that you're no longer limited to a single active website (like XP/IIS5.1), this removes lots of unneccesary pain from your life.

Contrary to the usual rumour mills, Vista isn't all bad. It's just a perception change.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide us with specific compatability issues with Vista?

I use Vista at home and work and develop on a variety of VS versions.  Most often in 2008.  There are no Vista specific issues that I run into on a normal basis.

The only big difference between using VS on Vista (and above) vs. XP and below is UAC.  I know a lot of people feel differently but I love UAC (strong unix/linux background).  UAC can affect your development cycle because it prevent you from doing potentially illegal operations (such as writing to %ProgramFiles% or HKLM).  It's possible to get the same effect on XP by leaving the Admins group but few people take that step.

Developing as a limited user (UAC route or lack of Admin) will **generally speaking** increase the reliability of your application.  So in general Vista may be tougher but it will produce a better app.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using XP for many years before and switched to Vista about one year ago. Other than that I was I able to actually see how much application runs on a Vista system, it did not make and real difference for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Microsoft tools, they'll all work just fine.  I can't vouch for gcc, but the Visual Studio stack works just fine.  Microsoft puts a lot of effort into making sure their tools work fine on their own operating systems.  Vista gets a bad rap, but most of it is undeserved now.

Comment: Agreed, when we had all the initial mucking about with VS05/SQL05 and were awaiting special patches there was maybe some justification for a bit of a moan, but they quickly sorted all that and it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

i recently switched to vista 64 ultimate since i decided it was worth the trouble(wanted to do directx 10 applications). i havent found any problem whatsoever only thing i would recomend is let visual studio run as administrator and dont disable uac!!!! it may be REALLY annoying but it's the best security feature vista has. i really havent had a problem about it since when i install program's i run them as administrator so they are not limited.

Answer (score 1):

Vista is nowhere near as bad as it was at launch.  Service Pack 1 fixed a lot of issues, regular patches have helped with others, and still more "problems" were the result of bad pr and perception rather than any real failing.

Even UAC isn't as bad as you may have heard.  The trick there is to just put it up with it for the first month maybe two, during your personal "burn in" period with your computer.  During this time you're installing and configuring lot of new software, changing a lot user and system settings, and in general just playing around.  So of course you see a lot of prompts here.  This is exactly what happened with all those reviews you saw online saying how bad UAC is: they were still in the burn in period for the operating system.

After about a month two things happen:
1.  You don't see as many prompts, because you're not making as many system changes.
2.  You get used to them, so that prompts that remain actually make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would wait for Windows 7. I am using that now for development. I've used Vista in the past, switched back to XP. But now going from 7 to XP is hell.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to +1 for using a beta OS for development, or -1 for using a beta OS for development!

Answer (score 0):

No problems with development on vista that I've found, and I've used a variety of compilers, CLRs, etc.

I do a bit of linux work, but that takes place in a VM.

VM's on modern processors are as fast as native, so if you run into a snag, load an XP VM and run with it.  Adds a little friction, but recent VMs overcome cut-n-paste issues, and with network mapped drives there's nothing you can't easily do.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but I'm using SQL 2008 and Visual Studio 2008.

Convince them to roll out a few laptops first and see if your particular development environment works in Vista.  If it doesn't work, then you can focus on fixing it before everyone is required to run Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista Security is quite better than earlier versions of Windows. Mainly because of User Account Control - UAC. Windows Vista will gives standard rights to all non-administrative application when user starts that app even if the user log on windows as an administator. This can cause trouble in terms of compatibility with applications that are designed to work with earlier versions of Windows. If you experience problems running these apps, you need to tell Windows Vista to give administrative rights to that particular app by right-click on the icon can click Run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download and install the [Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=90e2942d-3ad1-4873-a2ee-4acc0aace5b6&displaylang=en).